# Basic Express server connecting to MongoDB w/ Mongoose returning an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Trying out mongo for the first time using mongoose and can't quite get it to read what I've got stored in mongo with a basic express setup. I've seen tutorials and this seems to be the same setup used to simply spit data onto a page in BSON/JSON format, however I'm just getting back an empty array. Am I missing something simple?

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var app = express();


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo');


var usersSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});


mongoose.model('users', usersSchema);


app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users) {
    res.send(users);
  });
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: If you're getting back an empty array, you're not looking in the right place, or it's empty?

Comment: I've made a db in mongo and all that.. any insights into my mongoose syntax potentially being off?

Comment: Did you try `mongoose.model('users').find({}, function(err ...`

Comment: Have you checked `err` to see if you're getting an error back?

Comment: Adding brackets to find didn't change anything.. still looking for an answer to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial I followed to setup mongo must have been old because inside mongo the 'users' collection was not being created. Following this tut I was able to properly create my users collection and spit out the BSON/JSON data in the browser like I wanted. http://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/how-to-create-mongodb-database-collection

So the express/mongoose syntax is correct, I just somehow didn't properly create a collection. I realized this when I ran `show collections` in mongo inside my 'mongo' database I created and saw no collections.

Answer (score 0):

attach the mongoose model to a variable then use it :

```
var modelM = mongoose.model('users', usersSchema);
```

and

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  modelM.find({}, 'name', function(err, users) {
     if(err) throw err;
     res.send(users);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Collections in MongoDB are created lazily, this means that before you post anything to the collection, it won't be created.!

If you change your script to:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var app = express();


    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo');


    var usersSchema = new Schema({
      name: String
    });


    mongoose.model('users', usersSchema);

    mongoose.model('users').create({name: 'This is a test'}, function(error, user){
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    }else{
        console.log('Created: '+ user.name);
    }
    })

    app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
      mongoose.model('users').find({}, function(err, users) {
        res.send(users);
      });
    });


    app.listen(3000);
```

You should create a collection with a user, and you will get an array of all the users in the db back.!